# simple grapesjs integration into angular, running into import problems

Tags: angular, typescript, grapesjs

Currently following this article https://esketchers.com/integration-of-grapesjs-with-angular/ to integrate grapesjs into my angular project, however I'm running into some issues.

When I import grapesjs into my .ts file using `import grapesjs from 'grapesjs';` and compile my project I get this error...

```
Error: node_modules/grapesjs/index.d.ts:29:5 - error TS7010: 'zeach', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.      

29     zeach(callback: (item: TModel) => void);
```

I tried looking online for more documentation but did not get much. I found this example that seems to work on stackblitz but didn't work in my project https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fnkhd4?file=src%2Fapp%2Feditor%2Feditor.components.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css.

**Not sure how to solve this or what this means? Does anyone have any ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, had to change the version for it to be compatible.
I used grapesjs@0.16.18 and grapesjs-preset-webpage@0.1.11.